# Borken bar instead of vertical bar Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm trying to write a script in Ubuntu Server 14.04. When I press the key for a vertical bar "|" my screen shows a broken bar "¦"

My keyboard is in spanish and the layout is latinamerican. All other keys are shown perfectly on the screen.

Could you help understand whats going on?

Comment: Does it still work as a pipe?  Could simply be a font issue.

Answer (score 1):

As a *workaround* you can use Unicode for that:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

or with this command:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 24 = bar"
```

check the value for keycode with:

```
xev
```

sample output:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0x233, subw 0x0, time 31839373, (54,162), root:(54,226),
    state 0x90, keycode 94 (keysym 0x7c, bar), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7c) "|"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7c) "|"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

---

make it permanent with this steps:

Open the file `.xinitrc`

```
nano ~/.xinitrc
```

and add this line:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Open the file `.Xmodmap`

```
nano ~/.Xmodmap
```

and add this line

```
keycode 24 = bar
```